# Managing user attributes for a SimpleSAMLphp Identity Provider

Tags: drupal-8, simplesamlphp

I successfully managed to install and use a few instances of SimpleSAMLphp both as Service Provider and Identity Provider (using the simple example user authentication).

Now I'm looking for a basic PHP App which manages the user account and attributes -- user, password, email, groups, password recovery, etc. -- and easily binds to the SimpleSAMLphp Idp as an authenticator.

I was very optimist about "Drupal + SimpleSAMLphp + drupalauth = Complete SAML Identity Provider (IdP)", but if to use Drupal, I would like to use Drupal 8 and not 7.

Do you know any other setup that could achieve something similar?

Comment: Hi Mic,Did you able to find a solution for this?